# How do edit a list (of equations) made with tocloft?

Tags: equations, tocloft

I use this for my list of equations:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\listequationsname}{Formelverzeichnis}
\newlistof[section]{myequations}{equ}{\listequationsname}
\newcommand{\myequations}[1]{%
\addcontentsline{equ}{myequations}{\protect\numberline{\theequation}#1}\par}
\setlength\cftmyequationsindent{1.5em}
\setlength\cftmyequationsnumwidth{2.3em}
\renewcommand{\cftequtitlefont}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}

\listofmyequations

\newpage

\begin{equation}\label{eq:Eq1}
  a=b
\end{equation}
\myequations{Abc \ref{eq:Eq1}}

\newpage

\begin{equation}\label{eq:Eq2}
  b=c
\end{equation}
\myequations{Xyz \ref{eq:Eq2}}  

\end{document}
```

The result is this:
[image: Latex Result]

It's nice, but I need the table like this:

**Formel 1:** Abc 1 . . . . . . 2

**Formel 2:** Xyz 2 . . . . . . 3

Answer (score 1):

Change the `\myequations` to

```
\newcommand{\myequations}[1]{%
  \addcontentsline{equ}{myequations}
    {\protect\numberline{\bfseries Formel~\theequation:}#1}\par}
```

and enlarge `\cftmyequationsnumwidth`.

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\newcommand{\listequationsname}{Formelverzeichnis}
\newlistof[section]{myequations}{equ}{\listequationsname}
\newcommand{\myequations}[1]{%
  \addcontentsline{equ}{myequations}
    {\protect\numberline{\bfseries Formel~\theequation:}#1}\par}
\setlength\cftmyequationsindent{1.5em}
\setlength\cftmyequationsnumwidth{5.5em}
\renewcommand{\cftequtitlefont}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}

\begin{document}

\listofmyequations
\newpage

\begin{equation}\label{eq:Eq1}
  a=b
\end{equation}
\myequations{Abc \ref{eq:Eq1}}

\newpage

\begin{equation}\label{eq:Eq2}
  b=c
\end{equation}
\myequations{Xyz \ref{eq:Eq2}}

\end{document}
```

[image]